# Cannon.js - How can I set rotation limits for a HingeConstraint?

Tags: javascript, cannon.js

I'd like to be able to set rotational limits on a hinge constraint with cannon.js

I've looked everywhere for an example and can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HingeConstraint in Cannon.js does not yet support rotation limits.